# How get all installed assemblies in a SQL Server database? (sys.assembly_modules doesn't show them)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I go into SQL Server Manager, I can see:

```
MyDatabase
->Programmability
  ->Assemblies
    ->Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
    ->MyAssembly
    ->Newtonsoft.Json
```

But when i run:

```
select * from sys.assembly_modules;
```

I get no rows.

*NOTE: I am logged in as 'sa'*

Why? How do i list the assemblies installed?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
select * from sys.assemblies
```